# How to select all items that have no orders?(that are not on any receipt)

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot

```
@Query(value="SELECT i.name\n" +
            "FROM item as i\n" +
            "INNER JOIN items_receipts as ir\n" +
            "    ON i.id = ir.item_id\n" +
            "INNER JOIN receipt as r\n" +
            "    ON ir.receipt_id = r.id\n" +
            "GROUP BY i.id\n" +
                "HAVING COUNT(r.id)=0"
            ,nativeQuery = true)
    List<String> fiveSales();
```

Why this query doesn't seem to work? Is it because the count is null or something else?[image]

Comment: your image is about a different structure, but take your query in workbench or so and try it first without joins and then add the joins and at last the having, so you can see what happens

Comment: Sorry old image changed order to receipt

Comment: The query would work, did you outer join the receipt tables, thus keeping the item rows that have no match. But I don't recommend this. With this method you count all the orders for all the items, only to find some items that have no order at all. It is easier to just select the items that have no entry in the item_receipts table (i.e. the DBMS can stop looking when it sees the first entry for an item in that table). Please see my answer on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining the tables. Thus you get all the ordered items. Now you look at that data set and for every item in that dataset you count the rows. The problem is: you want the items that are *not* in the data set.

For lookups use `[NOT] EXISTS` or `[NOT] IN`.

```
select *
from item
where id not in (select item_id from items_receipts);
```

or

```
select *
from item i
where not exists (select null from items_receipts ir where ir.item_id = i.id);
```

Comment: I like `select null`. It may be counterintuitive for many developers, but it's absolutely correct.

Comment: Does mysql not ignore all Select columns independet what is in there?

Comment: It is working thank you :)

Comment: @nbk: Yes, in an `EXISTS` clause the selected columns don't matter in MySQL. In some other DBMS, though, you can get a syntax error when there is an aggregation in the subquery and the selected columns render the subquery invalid. `NULL` is a good option hence in my opinion, as it works in any case and any DBMS.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i prefer 1 so it sit is clear you you get

Comment: @nbk: yep, that's a matter of personal preference. I don't consider 1 more readable than null. If you wanted great readability you could select `where not exists (select 'a matching row' from ...)` :-)